# Skip a level with {{ block.super }}

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a 3rd party app that defines a bunch of templates (somewhat similar to how django-admin works). The base template defines a block with some content:

`base.html:`

```
<!doctype HTML>

<html><head>
<!-- blah blah -->

{% block very_kewl %}
    <marquee><b><i><u>this is very kewl</marquee></b></i></u>
    <!-- disclaimer: this is not valid HTML! -->
{% endblock very_kewl %}

</html>
```

Then a child template clears the block:

`actual_page.html:`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{# very many other stuff, part 1 #}

{% block very_kewl %}{% endblock %}

{# very many other stuff, part 2 #}
```

---

What I want to achieve is to keep the "very kewl" content on the page.

An approach that works is to simply copy the entire `actual_page.html` into the project template dir and omit the line `{% block very_kewl %}{% endblock %}`. This works, but the downside is that I also have to repeat all the other parts of the template, some of which are likely to change in the future.

So the question is **how can I show that "very kewl" content from the base template without also repeating all the other stuff** in the `actual_page.html`?

Ideally, I would be able to do something like this, but of course, this doesn't work:

`project_templates/actual_page.html:`

```
{% extends 'actual_page.html' %}

{% block very_kewl %}{{ block.super.super }}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If you extend `actual_page.html` and copy the desired content from `base.html` into the `very_kewl` block, you'll only have to keep that part updated manually - better than copying and changing `actual_page.html`. No better ideas for now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep the HTML used in the base template's block as a separate template?

`project_template/partials/very_kewl.html`

```
<marquee><b><i><u>this is very kewl</marquee></b></i></u>
<!-- disclaimer: this is not valid HTML! -->
```

Now, just include it wherever the HTML needs to be used.

`project_template/base.html`

```
<!doctype HTML>

<html><head>
<!-- blah blah -->

{% block very_kewl %}
    {% include 'partials/very_kewl.html' %}
{% endblock very_kewl %}

</html>
```

And in the grandchild `project_templates/actual_page.html`

```
{% extends 'actual_page.html' %}

{% block very_kewl %}{% include 'partials/very_kewl.html' %}{% endblock %}
```

So even at some point the block gets cleared up, the childs of that template can simply include the required HTML.

Comment: This would work of course, but the templates in question are from a 3rd party app. I'll clarify the question.

Comment: if `{% block very_kewl %}` is defined by the 3rd party app, then you can encapsulate this block under a new block, `{% block my_very_kewl %}{% block very_kewl %}{% endblock very_kewl %}{% endblock my_very_kewl%}`, and then call `very_kewl` in the grandchild, just like including templates

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Not 100% sure it will work, but I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Basically I'm proposing to use `my_very_kewl` everywhere instead of `very_kewl` and use `very_kewl` only when the parent empties it up, but child needs it.